# Why is Redis Sorted Set using so much memory overhead?

Tags: web, redis, sortedset

I am designing a Redis datastore with ~3000 sorted set keys, each with 60 - 300 items each around 250 bytes in size.

`used_memory_overhead` = 1055498028 bytes and `used_memory_dataset`= 9681332 bytes. This ratio seems way too high. `used_memory_dataset_perc` is less than 1%. Memory usage is exceeding the max of 1.16G and causing keys to be evicted.

Do sorted sets really have 99% memory overhead? Will I have to just find another solution? I just want a list of values that is sorted by a field in the value.

Here's the output of `MEMORY INFO` . `used_memory_dataset_perc` just keeps decreasing until it's <1% and eventually the max memory is exceeded

```
# Memory
used_memory:399243696
used_memory_human:380.75M
used_memory_rss:493936640
used_memory_rss_human:471.05M
used_memory_peak:1249248448
used_memory_peak_human:1.16G
used_memory_peak_perc:31.96%
used_memory_overhead:390394038
used_memory_startup:4263448
used_memory_dataset:8849658
used_memory_dataset_perc:2.24%
allocator_allocated:399390096
allocator_active:477728768
allocator_resident:499613696
used_memory_lua:37888
used_memory_lua_human:37.00K
used_memory_scripts:0
used_memory_scripts_human:0B
number_of_cached_scripts:0
maxmemory:1248854016
maxmemory_human:1.16G
maxmemory_policy:volatile-lru
allocator_frag_ratio:1.20
allocator_frag_bytes:78338672
allocator_rss_ratio:1.05
allocator_rss_bytes:21884928
rss_overhead_ratio:0.99
rss_overhead_bytes:-5677056
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.24
mem_fragmentation_bytes:94804256
mem_not_counted_for_evict:0
mem_replication_backlog:0
mem_clients_slaves:0
mem_clients_normal:385555150
mem_aof_buffer:0
mem_allocator:jemalloc-5.1.0
active_defrag_running:0
lazyfree_pending_objects:0
```

In case it is relevant, I am using AWS Elasticache

Comment: You should this ask question here https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/